# Find possible matches for a string in a website in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am currently learning Matlab and I am trying to find number of possible matches for a string in a website. It is very similar to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> function.
I tried to store the website content in a string called str using urlread('...') and then tried to compare the string I am looking for (example: "Program") with str, but it didn't work.
here is my code:

```
str = urlread('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_program');
keyword = 'Program';
TF = strcmpi(str,keyword)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`strfind`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) for this task

```
str = urlread('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_program');
keyword = 'Program';
keywordIDX = strfind(str, keyword);
```

The variable `keywordIDX` will contain all indices of the occurrences of the keyword in question.

The function [`strcmpi`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi.html) just compares whether two strings are identical (ignoring whether letter cases are the same).

Answer (score 4):

Another powerful tool for string handling and manipulations is regular expression.
See [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) and [`regexprep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) for more details.